# visual code c++: ros and intellisense

Tags: c++, intellisense, ros

do you have also problems with the automatic code completion of Visual Code?
if I create an object of a class, the list of attributs and methods are completely confused. I get suggestions for methods of completely different classes see here [image]

Is that a matter of settings or is the "intellisense" of Visual Code just crap?

(By the way am using Ubuntu 16.04, visual code 1.25 with ajshort.ros and ms-vscode.cpptools extension)

Best regards 
Tobias

Comment: Have you tried re-indexing your solution?

Comment: How can I do this in Visual Code?